# Codeigniter database config table

Tags: codeigniter

My question is about codeigniter. Someone recently handled me a codeigniter project when I tried running the project on localhost I found its base url is some IP address. Then I found it is configured in database config table.
The table looks like

```
Key               | Value
profiling_enabled | b:0;
event_name        | s:21:"some name";
base_url          | s:20:"http://some ip address/";
version           | s:3:"0.6";
config_level      | i:2;
```

I changed the base url to localhost IP but it redirect me to xampp home, changed config.php, removed the table but it didn't work. I am searching internet for hours please help and don't be upset if its a stupid one :P

Comment: Maybe the .htaccess is not present or not properly configured, also dont forget to add the trailing slash on some ip address/

Comment: what you want to do??

Comment: I want to run it on localhost. but the given IP address is some private IP which cannot be accessed. I changed the "http://some ip address/" to "http://127.0.0.1/project/" but it just redirect to xampp home page. the .htaccess is present.

Comment: @Nadeshwaran I found some source there https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Storing-variables-config-in-database but its is not descriptive.

Comment: you have to narrow down your problem
@first i would try to install a clean CI installation - and try to run it from your directory - (for example you create a directory called project_ci  and try to get access via localhost/project_ci/ - if that works - you know that you don't have a server problem here

Comment: Thank you all. I found its source at http://badgeentry.sourceforge.net/